# Excel: Naming results of intermediate calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm making a marginal tax rate calculator and am finding that my formulas are getting quite large. Gross income, for example, is subject to a standard deduction and personal exemption. After subtracting out these exemptions, I calculate the tax due.

I'd like to have income net of deductions "renamed" so that I don't have to use the same unwieldly expression in my database lookups, so instead of

```
vlookup(gross - Deductions!ref1 - Deductions!ref2, ...)
```

I want

```
vlookup(incomeNetOfDeductions, ...)
```

Is there an easy and clean way to do this?

Comment: You didn't mention what version of excel you are using.  In later versions of excellent  go to the formula ribbon and select named range.  Type the formula there and then you can do what you want.

Comment: Not use Excel to finance). See as sample `POISSON` function, and calculate at another programming language.

Comment: named ranges are something you should look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are looking to use [Named ranges](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).

The quickest way to give an area or a cell a name is with the "Name Box", wich is left of your "Formula bar", right under the ribbon. Select a cell or range, click inside the Name Box and give it a name. In any cell or worksheet, you can now use that name.

To show the names in use and/or to edit them, go to the "Formula" ribbon and click "Name manager". This opens a window with a list of all the names in use.